# CouchDB for a forum?

Tags: mysql, database-design, couchdb

Will couchDB be better for storing the forum posts/topics then MySQL? assuming there is proper caching (i.e memcached being used).

It seems at first glance that CouchDB is made for this, the whole document orientated design fits perfectly but I'm more concerned about performance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB is *fast*.  It will meet your needs perfectly.  It's good for a forum as each post and all related comments/posts in a thread will be self contained.  CouchDB maps are, as far as I've seen, faster than MySQL Joins when MySQL has a large dataset.

I would say go for it.

Edit:

If you want an example of how CouchDB can be used in a decent way, check out [skinnyboard](http://github.com/fmiopensource/skinny_board).  It's an agile planning tool and contains tasks on a story, and stories on a board, all with permissions in one CouchDB document.  The code is a little messy in some places, but it's a good example of data encapsulation using CouchDB.

Comment: This benchmark, comparing Couch and MySql doesn't say that. http://www.codeweblog.com/couchdb-vs-mysql-insert-performance-test-data-of-the-speed-test/ If the main goal here is really performance (in all ways), I would not go through CouchDB. It can be faster for queries, but maybe MongoDB could be a faster JSON-db for your needs. It is not that RESTful, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! ill check out both skinnyboard and mongodb